# Is there any way to be notified when an IntelliJ plugin is uninstalled?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a plugin for Android Studio and would like to know when the user uninstalls it to clean some property files.

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't that be just part of the uninstall process - to clean up anything you've left behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JetBrains developer answered the question in the JetBrains Developer Community (https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5561188):

> No, there is no such way. There is usually no harm in leaving unused data in the settings, so we didn't implement any mechanism for cleaning it up.